# Getting start and end indices of string in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a df that looks like this:

```
|Index|Value|Anomaly|
---------------------
|0    |4    |       |
|1    |2    |Anomaly|
|2    |1    |Anomaly|
|3    |2    |       |
|4    |6    |Anomaly|
```

I want to get the start and end indices of the consecutive anomaly counts so in this case, it will be `[[1,2],[4]]`

I understand I have to use `.shift` and `.cumsum` but I am lost and I hope someone would be able to enlighten me.

Comment: oh oops, will edit accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get consecutive groups taking the cumsum of the Boolean Series that checks where the value is not 'Anomoly'. Use `where` so that we only only take the 'Anomoly' rows. Then we can loop over the groups and grab the indices.

```
m = df['Anomaly'].ne('Anomaly')

[[idx[0], idx[-1]] if len(idx) > 1 else [idx[0]] 
 for idx in df.groupby(m.cumsum().where(~m)).groups.values()]
#[[1, 2], [4]]
```

---

Or if you want to use a much longer `groupby` you can get the first and last index, then drop duplicates (to deal with streaks of only 1) and get it into a list of lists. This is much slower though

```
(df.reset_index().groupby(m.cumsum().where(~m))['index'].agg(['first', 'last'])
   .stack()
   .drop_duplicates()
   .groupby(level=0).agg(list)
   .tolist())
#[[1, 2], [4]]
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. Looks like i have to really read thru pandas documentaion!

Comment: @CheeJiaYuan yes, in the second call you can comment out the later parts and run them line by line to see what each step does.